# Override python logging for test efficiency

Tags: python, performance, unit-testing, logging

In many cases unit-tests are significantly slowed down by the use of python's `logging` package. Assuming logging isn't essential to the test, how would you cleanly override `logging` per-test, so that log commands would be effectively skipped.

Assume the use of multiple loggers such as in:

```
logger1 = logging.getLogger('logger1')
logger2 = logging.getLogger('logger2')
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Logging can be [disabled](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.disable) by calling

```
logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)
```

and turned back on with

```
logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)
```

However, even after disabling logging, a logging statement such as `logger.info` would still cause Python to do a few attribute lookups and function calls before reaching the `isEnabledFor` method. Still, this might be good enough.

**Option 2:**

Use mocking:

```
class MockLogger(object):
    def debug(msg, *args, **kwargs): pass
    def info(msg, *args, **kwargs): pass
    def warn(msg, *args, **kwargs): pass
    def error(msg, *args, **kwargs): pass
    def critical(msg, *args, **kwargs): pass

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_func(self):
        _logger1=testmodule.logger1
        _logger2=testmodule.logger2
        testmodule.logger1=MockLogger()
        testmodule.logger2=MockLogger()
        # perform test
        testmodule.logger1=_logger1
        testmodule.logger2=_logger2
```

This will reduce the time consumed by logging statements to the time it takes to do one attribute lookup and one (noop) function call. If that's not satisfactory, I think the only option left is removing the logging statements themselves.

Comment: should it not be `logging.disable(logging.FATAL)` as OP wanted to disable all logging, not only lower levels.